# GitLab multiple runners, exchanging artifacts

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm already using gitlab CI on smaller projects, but now I'm looking into using gitlab as CI for a larger project.

How can I pass build artifacts (bunch of binary files etc) between two gitlab-runners running on two different physical machines?

Context:
I have a large repository, which produces a lot of artifacts during the build. Obviously this takes time, so I'd like to build on a beefy multi-core machine. If the build passes, I want to test in parallel across many other (smaller) machines. These test-machines are hooked up to many different kinds of equipment. Equipment that I don't want to bother the beefy machine with.

I understand `artifacts:` and `dependencies:` should address this, but that uses a local cache as far as I can tell.

The build artefacts weigh in at ~4GB so somehow that data must be transferred.

Can gitlab help with this natively, or do I need a pattern of build+push followed by a fetch+test? (To say, artifactory CEPH NFS etc)

I imagine my needs aren't unique so something must already exist for this.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path: `artifacts` is what you are looking for. Runners do not store the *artifacts* they build, but they upload them to the GitLab instance.

Now, where GitLab stores them is a different topic, and if you manage your GitLab installation, you can take a look at the administration documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/job_artifacts.html

You can also retrieve artifacts through APIs, if you have any special need, but `artifacts` and `dependencies` should be more than enough for your use case: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#get-job-artifacts